# MySQL / PHP - Getting a fatal error when trying to use an array?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting the following error when trying to access the page I'm on.

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in /.../comment.php on line 44

Can anyone help with what the problem might be? Line 44 is below...

```
$posts = mysqli_query($sql, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE postid = '$related'") or die($posts . "<br/>" . mysqli_error($sql));

$postsId = $posts['postid']; // <-- This is line 44
```

Comment: $posts is not an array, that's what it's telling you. You need to look at fetch_array

Comment: this is correct answer Hammerstein. you had to post it as answer.

Comment: @heximal I don't like posting things like that if I'm not providing links or more information. I'm not worried about points, more about helping.

Comment: this is the point of SO. next time a visitor will see your accepted answer and will know this is the solution

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you everything you need to know: `$posts` contains a [mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) from which you need to get the actual data first using `mysqli_fetch_array()`, for example.

Comment: function is mysqli_fetch_array.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
$posts = mysqli_query($sql, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE postid = '$related'") or die($posts . "<br/>" . mysqli_error($sql));
$postData = mysqli_fetch_array($posts);
$postsId  = $postData['postid'];
```

Answer (score 0):

`$posts` is of type `mysqli_result`. It's not an array. An array would describe a table row, but you'll get probably multiple table rows with your SQL query. Therefore you have to loop them all before you get you array with data. There are some possibilities to do this:

- [mysqli_result::fetch_object()](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php)
- [mysqli_result::fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)
- [mysqli_result::fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)
- ...

**Example**

```
$posts = mysqli_query($sql, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE postid = '$related'") or die($posts . "<br/>" . mysqli_error($sql));    

while ($row = $posts->fetch_array()) {
    // is_array($row) === true
    var_dump($row["postid"]);
}

// or

while ($row = $posts->fetch_object()) {
    // ($row instanceof stdClass) === true
    var_dump($row->postid);
}
```